# Static variables inside macros

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm looking at some code and think the whole logic doesn't make sense here. It seem quite poor to have a macro like this. 
As an example, I use this macro twice and I get both strings to output.

```
TESTING("hello");
TESTING("world");
```

1. The preprocessor simply replaces the identifier with the block of code, it is the same as copy/pasting the code, so shouldn't the compiler give a redefinition error for firstPass, if using this macro multiple times? (If you manually paste in `main`, `static bool firstPass = true;` multiple times, the compiler will give an error.)
2. If `firstPass` is `static`, it is created and initialized only once. So using this macro multiple times, shouldn't produce any results (besides the first use) since the flag was set to `false`, yet it still does `cout` every time.

A bit confused.

```
#define TESTING(input)                           \
{                                                \
   static bool firstPass = true;                 \
   if (firstPass) {                              \
     std::cout << input;                         \
     firstPass = false;                          \
   }                                             \
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's bad to use macros instead of function templates.

Comment: This code is pointless.  Every time you call it you will have a new `firstPass` due to scoping rules.

Comment: Your misunderstanding seems to be with the macro contents (specifically the block, `{...}`) rather than the macro itself. That is, if you manually copy and paste the macro contents like you say, you have the same issue without any macros involved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This macro cannot work as intended. The key to why the compiler allows it is the `{ }` surrounding the `static bool firstPass`. That creates a new scope, which allows the new variable to hide any other variable by that name. When that scope ends, the static is no longer visible.

Because of the new scopes, this is legal:

```
void f()
{
    int i = 0;
    {
        int i = 1;
        {
            int i = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

This would work the way it was intended, by moving firstPass out of the macro.

```
static bool firstPass = true;
#define TESTING(input)                           \
{                                                \
   if (firstPass) {                              \
     std::cout << input;                         \
     firstPass = false;                          \
   }                                             \
}
```

**ETA**: Or maybe it does work as intended. With the static bool inside the macro, each call site will print its output exactly once, because each call site has its own instance of the firstPass flag. With the static bool outside the macro only the first call site to be reached will report it's output and only the first time it's reached.

So with the static bool inside the macro,

```
f()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
    {
         TESTING( "A\n" );
         TESTING( "B\n" );
         TESTING( "C\n" );
    }
}

int main()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) 
        f();
    return 0;
}
```

will print

```
A
B
C
```

but with the static bool outside the macro, it will print only

```
A
```

Comment: Funny; I'd say it works exactly as intended.  The first time each `TESTING` invocation is invoked, it reports that it is run — and not thereafter.  But then the question becomes "what is the intended behaviour".  We're both correct (for our assumptions about what is intended); they're just different interpretations or assumptions about what is intended.

Comment: Ahhhh, I hadn't thought about the intent being to only report the first time through any particular call site.